# CoreData: Convert textField.Text to Integer 32

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data, type-conversion

How do I convert a **`textField.Text`** to an **`NSInteger64`** to store it in a **`CoreData`** database? I tried something like this but gave me a warning:

```
[newEntry setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:self.mililitriTextField.text] forKey:@"mililitri"];
```

**`Warning: Incompatible pointer to Integer conversion`...**

And I also want to convert a **`TextField.Text`** to a **`Double`** to insert it in the **`Coredata`** database. Can someone tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like:

```
[newEntry setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self.mililitriTextField.text integerValue]] forKey:@"mililitri"];
```

You really should split this out a little bit, for example:

```
NSNumber * numberToSave = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self.mililitriTextField.text integerValue]];
if(numberToSave)
{
    [newEntry setValue: numberToSave forKey: @"mililitri"];
}
```

which is a bit more code, but helps you (or somebody else) to understand the flow when this code needs to be looked at later on.

Answer (score 0):

textField.text is an NSString object.  Why would you try to convert a string to a number for storage?  Store the string as a string.  Use `[newEntry setValue: self.mililitriTextField.text forKey:@"mililitri"];`

If your textField contains an integer and you want to store that integer, then use `[NSNumber numberWithInteger: self.mililitriTextField.text.integerValue]` to get the integer.